# Jump to a particular page of scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a gridViewControll .  What i wish : when i click on some picture I want to go to another view controller and display the picture clicked and also to swipe between all images from the gridView in the same order.

So, in gridView , i set the id for picture clicked and i sent it to the new view controller and it's ok , but when i swap the pictures starts from begin .

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
              for (int i = 1 ; i< 402 ; i++){

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"image_%d" , i]];
        [imageArray addObject: image];


    }


    for (int i = 0; i < [imageArray count]; i++) {

        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        imageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

    }
    CGRect frame;

    frame.origin=self.scrollView.frame.origin;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;


    UIImageView *imagetest=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    imagetest.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:self.data];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imagetest];

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * [imageArray count], scrollView.frame.size.height);


}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be getting image index (let say, **int indexNumber**), which has been selected from image array. 
So you can use that code:

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * indexNumber, 0);

[self.scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.